# Array Post Binding Asp Net MVC

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, post

I'm having some trouble binding arrays on Asp Net MVC, when the object returns in the post method, the arrays properties returns null, here is a sample code that i made simulating the problem:

Any glue is welcome :)

I Have this 2 classes:

```
  public class Class1
  {
    public string SampleProperty { get; set; }
    public Class2[] SampleClass2Array { get; set; }
  }

  public class Class2
  {
    public string SampleProperty { get; set; }
    public string[] SampleStringArray { get; set; }
  }
```

This 2 Actions:

```
public ActionResult SampleAction()
{
  var model = new Class1()
  {
    SampleProperty = "class 1 property 1 value",
    SampleClass2Array = new Class2[]
    {
      new Class2()
      {
        SampleProperty = "position 1 class 2 property 1 value",
        SampleStringArray = "one,two,3,4,5,6".Split(new char[]{','})
      },
      new Class2()
      {
        SampleProperty = "position 2 class 2 property 1 value",
        SampleStringArray = "seven,8,9,10".Split(new char[]{','})
      }
    }
  };

  return View(model);
}
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SampleAction(Class1 model)
{
  Dictionary<string, object> parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
  Request.Params.CopyTo(parameters);

  return View();
}
```

And the view:

```
    <legend>Class1</legend>
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SampleProperty)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SampleProperty)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SampleProperty)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.SampleClass2Array.Length; i++)
        {
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SampleClass2Array[i]) <br />               
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.SampleClass2Array[i])    
        }
    </div>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
    </p>
```

With this EditorTemplate

```
@model TestBinding.Models.Class2
<p>
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SampleProperty)
</p>
<p>
    Content</p>
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.SampleStringArray.Length; i++)
{
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.SampleStringArray[i]) <br />               
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.SampleStringArray[i])
}
<br />
```

And the Post is returning (i took that from the dictionary):

```
{[SampleProperty, class 1 property 1 value]}    
{[SampleClass2Array[0].SampleProperty, position 1 class 2 property 1 value]}    
{[SampleClass2Array[0].SampleStringArray[0], one]}  
{[SampleClass2Array[0].SampleStringArray[1], two]}  
{[SampleClass2Array[0].SampleStringArray[2], 3]}    
{[SampleClass2Array[0].SampleStringArray[3], 4]}    
{[SampleClass2Array[0].SampleStringArray[4], 5]}    
{[SampleClass2Array[0].SampleStringArray[5], 6]}    
{[SampleClass2Array[0], TestBinding.Models.Class2]} 
{[SampleClass2Array[1].SampleProperty, position 2 class 2 property 1 value]}    
{[SampleClass2Array[1].SampleStringArray[0], seven]}    
{[SampleClass2Array[1].SampleStringArray[1], 8]}    
{[SampleClass2Array[1].SampleStringArray[2], 9]}    
{[SampleClass2Array[1].SampleStringArray[3], 10]}   
{[SampleClass2Array[1], TestBinding.Models.Class2]}
```

And the model object in the post view:

```
model   {TestBinding.Models.Class1} TestBinding.Models.Class1
SampleClass2Array   {TestBinding.Models.Class2[2]}  TestBinding.Models.Class2[]
[0] null    TestBinding.Models.Class2
[1] null    TestBinding.Models.Class2
SampleProperty  "class 1 property 1 value"  string
```

Comment: i got it, too much to read :)

Comment: Did you figure out the issue? Can you post an answer? I'm having trouble with editors for a string array property.

Comment: may be this is what you are looking for.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6518189/bind-model-during-post-of-form-inside-editortemplate-on-array-multiple-bind-pr